# How can I put array into function input and then return it in Java

Tags: java, function

I'm new to JAVA and I want to give the function an array with strings,
so that in a future version of code I could reuse it.
I don't know how to do this and I would like to ask for help.
Thank you!

```
package Lesson1;



public class TicTacToe {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String field[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
        board(field);
        System.out.println("Choose your field");
        String printX = "X";
        String printO = "O";

        
    }

        public static String[] board(String[] field){
            System.out.println("Printing board");
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println(String.format("| $s | $s | $s |",field[1],field[2],field[3]));
            System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
            System.out.println(String.format("| $s | $s | $s |",field[4],field[5],field[6]));
            System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
            System.out.println(String.format("| $s | $s | $s |",field[7],field[8],field[9]));
            System.out.println("-------------");
            return field;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but you want to use `%s` and not `$s` in `String.format`.

Comment: Isn't `public static String[] board(String[] field){ ... }` the method you need?

Comment: You are already creating a board function with String[] field parameter. But the way you are accessing the array is wrong. Since you have 9 elements in the array and indexing in Java is 0 based, you need to use field[0] to field[8]

Comment: @hithacker yes already corrected fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am correctly getting your point then,
you want to send array as argument to function.
so your code is correct need some correction.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String field[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
        board(field);
        System.out.println("Choose your field");
        String printX = "X";
        String printO = "O";

    }

    public static String[] board(String[] field) {
        System.out.println("Printing board");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println(String.format("| %s | %s | %s |", field[0], field[1], field[2]));
        System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
        System.out.println(String.format("| %s | %s | %s |", field[3], field[4], field[5]));
        System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
        System.out.println(String.format("| %s | %s | %s |", field[6], field[7], field[8]));
        System.out.println("-------------");
        return field;

    }
```

first 1 : array start with index 0 , if you start with 1 you will get array index out of bound exception.

second 2 : for formatting string, replace $ with % as format specifier.

answer :

### Printing board

### | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---|---|---|
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
|---|---|---|
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

Choose your field

Answer (score 0):

Index of the array should be start from Zero
It should start like this

```
field[0],field[1],field[2]
```

Comment: Great ! add a the answer as useful

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String fields[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    String sameFields[] = board(fields);
    System.out.printf("| %s |", sameFields[0]);
}

public static String[] board(String[] fields){
    if (fields.length < 9) return fields;
    System.out.println("Printing board");
    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.printf("| %s | %s | %s |%n",fields[0],fields[1],fields[2]);
    System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
    System.out.printf("| %s | %s | %s |%n",fields[3],fields[4],fields[5]);
    System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
    System.out.printf("| %s | %s | %s |%n",fields[6],fields[7],fields[8]);
    System.out.println("-------------");
    return fields;
}
```